# gradle: how to connect proguard with artifacts / add custom artifact?

Tags: java, gradle, build.gradle

i want to sign and upload to maven repo jar file processed by proguard. the whole pipeline worked correctly but now i want to sign and upload not the jar file created by jar task but the one created by proguard.

relevant part of my `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'maven'
apply plugin: 'signing'

group = 'com.mycompany'
version = '1.0.0'
// no explicit jar declaration

task proguard(type: proguard.gradle.ProGuardTask, dependsOn: 'jar') {

   injars  "$buildDir/libs/${jar.baseName}-${version}.jar" 
      //WHAT'S NEEDED TO CHANGE IT TO: ${jar.baseName}-${version}-original.jar

   outjars "$buildDir/libs/${jar.baseName}-${version}-processed.jar"
      // WHAT'S NEEDED TO CHANGE IT TO: ${jar.baseName}-${version}.jar

  ...
}

artifacts {
        archives jar, javadocJar // HOW TO ADD PROGUARD OUTPUT HERE?
}

signing {
        sign configurations.archives
}

uploadArchives {
   repositories {
       mavenDeployer {
          beforeDeployment { MavenDeployment deployment -> 
                                                signing.signPom(deployment) }
   ...
}
```

i know i can simply replace filename just before proguard task but this way i'll loose incremental builds: when original jar is renamed and proguard task fails, next build will unnecessary create jar again

Answer (score 0):

```
def obfsJar =
    artifacts.add(
            'archives', file(proguard.outputs.files.singleFile)) {
        type('jar')
        builtBy(proGuardTask)
    }

publishing {
publications {
    artifactoryPublications(MavenPublication) {
        artifact obfsJar
        }
    }
}
```